# SQL Server 2014: How to include header and detail in csv export

Tags: sql-server, csv, t-sql, ssis, sql-server-2014

I am trying to produce a script to export csv file to show header record and a corresponding detail record.

As an example the output needs to be

```
20138000100012, H,  2013800010, 03.04.2017, WK, 001,    2,  21.05.1984, NULL,   C
20138000100012, D,  INSURE, 0.71
20138000100012, D,  RENT,   98.58
20138000200060, H,  2013800020, 02.04.2018, WK, 006,    0,  25.05.2009, NULL,   C
20138000200060, D,  INSURE, 0.80
20138000200060, D,  RENT,   98.58
20138000500052, D,  LAUNDR, 1.29
```

I have attempted to produce that using the T-SQL script below:

```
select * 
from 
    (select 
         cast(dbo.[RE-TENANCY].[TENANCY-REF] as nvarchar) AS [0],
         'H' as [RowLevel],
         substring(convert(varchar(10),dbo.[RE-TENANCY].[TENANCY-REF]), 1, 10) AS [1],
         -- convert(varchar,dbo.[IH-PLACE-CHG].[START-DATE],104) AS [  ]
         format(dbo.[IH-PLACE-CHG].[START-DATE], 'dd.MM.yyyy') AS [2],
         dbo.[RE-TENANCY].[RENT-GROUP] AS [3], 
         cast(substring( dbo.[RE-TENANCY].[TENANCY-REF],11,3) as nvarchar) AS [4]
, cast(substring( dbo.[RE-TENANCY].[TENANCY-REF],14,1) as nvarchar) AS [5]
, cast(format(dbo.[RE-TENANCY].[TNCY-START], 'dd.MM.yyyy') as nvarchar) AS [6]
, cast(format(dbo.[RE-TENANCY].[TNCY-END], 'dd.MM.yyyy') as nvarchar) AS [7]
, substring(dbo.[RE-TENANCY].[TNCY-STATUS],1,1) AS [8]
    FROM            
        dbo.[RE-EX-RAISE-DEBIT-DTL] 
    INNER JOIN
        dbo.[RE-TENANCY] ON dbo.[RE-EX-RAISE-DEBIT-DTL].REFERENCE = dbo.[RE-TENANCY].[TENANCY-REF] 
    INNER JOIN
        dbo.[IH-PLACE-CHG] ON substring(dbo.[RE-TENANCY].[TENANCY-REF],1,10) = dbo.[IH-PLACE-CHG].[PLACE-REF]

    union

select cast(dbo.[RE-TENANCY].[TENANCY-REF] as nvarchar) AS [0]
,'D' as [RowLevel]

, dbo.[RE-EX-RAISE-DEBIT-DTL].[ACCOUNT-CODE] AS [1]
, convert(varchar,[dbo].[RE-EX-RAISE-DEBIT-DTL].[CHARGE-AMT]) AS [2]
, '' AS [3]
, '' AS [4]
, '' AS [5]
, '' AS [6]
, '' AS [7]
, '' AS [8]
FROM            dbo.[RE-EX-RAISE-DEBIT-DTL] INNER JOIN
                         dbo.[RE-TENANCY] ON dbo.[RE-EX-RAISE-DEBIT-DTL].REFERENCE = dbo.[RE-TENANCY].[TENANCY-REF] INNER JOIN
                         dbo.[IH-PLACE-CHG] ON substring(dbo.[RE-TENANCY].[TENANCY-REF],1,10) = dbo.[IH-PLACE-CHG].[PLACE-REF]


) AS HBfile order by cast(HBfile.[0] as bigint), HBfile.[6] desc
```

but this code incorrectly generates the results below:

```
20138000100012, H,  2013800010, 03.04.2017, WK, 001,    2,  21.05.1984, NULL,   C
20138000100012, H,  2013800010, 04.04.2016, WK, 001,    2,  21.05.1984, NULL,   C
20138000100012, H,  2013800010, 02.04.2018, WK, 001,    2,  21.05.1984, NULL,   C
20138000100012, D,  INSURE, 0.71
20138000100012, D,  RENT,   98.58
20138000200060, H,  2013800020, 02.04.2018, WK, 006,    0,  25.05.2009, NULL,   C
20138000200060, H,  2013800020, 03.04.2017, WK, 006,    0,  25.05.2009, NULL,   C
20138000200060, H,  2013800020, 04.04.2016, WK, 006,    0,  25.05.2009, NULL,   C
20138000200060, D,  INSURE, 0.80
20138000200060, D,  RENT,   98.58
20138000500060, D,  LAUNDR, 1.29
```

Any thoughts, assistance appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: I'd replace union with union all. Union takes the unnecessary step of removing duplicates. Would an order by [TENANCY-REF],RowLevel desc solve your issue?

Comment: you have an amazing answer. why ignoring it??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Trying to figure out the issue

Since the duplication is in the Headers part then you should take a look at the headers query:

```
select * 
from 
    (select 
         cast(dbo.[RE-TENANCY].[TENANCY-REF] as nvarchar) AS [0],
         'H' as [RowLevel],
         substring(convert(varchar(10),dbo.[RE-TENANCY].[TENANCY-REF]), 1, 10) AS [1],
         -- convert(varchar,dbo.[IH-PLACE-CHG].[START-DATE],104) AS [  ]
         format(dbo.[IH-PLACE-CHG].[START-DATE], 'dd.MM.yyyy') AS [2],
         dbo.[RE-TENANCY].[RENT-GROUP] AS [3], 
         cast(substring( dbo.[RE-TENANCY].[TENANCY-REF],11,3) as nvarchar) AS [4]
, cast(substring( dbo.[RE-TENANCY].[TENANCY-REF],14,1) as nvarchar) AS [5]
, cast(format(dbo.[RE-TENANCY].[TNCY-START], 'dd.MM.yyyy') as nvarchar) AS [6]
, cast(format(dbo.[RE-TENANCY].[TNCY-END], 'dd.MM.yyyy') as nvarchar) AS [7]
, substring(dbo.[RE-TENANCY].[TNCY-STATUS],1,1) AS [8]
    FROM            
        dbo.[RE-EX-RAISE-DEBIT-DTL] 
    INNER JOIN
        dbo.[RE-TENANCY] ON dbo.[RE-EX-RAISE-DEBIT-DTL].REFERENCE = dbo.[RE-TENANCY].[TENANCY-REF] 
    INNER JOIN
        dbo.[IH-PLACE-CHG] ON substring(dbo.[RE-TENANCY].[TENANCY-REF],1,10) = dbo.[IH-PLACE-CHG].[PLACE-REF]
```

This query contains 2 inner joins which means that the rows generated can be more than the sources count if the join is not made on 1-1 relation.

After checking the output you provided:

```
20138000100012, H,  2013800010, 03.04.2017, WK, 001,    2,  21.05.1984, NULL,   C
20138000100012, H,  2013800010, 04.04.2016, WK, 001,    2,  21.05.1984, NULL,   C
20138000100012, H,  2013800010, 02.04.2018, WK, 001,    2,  21.05.1984, NULL,   C
20138000100012, D,  INSURE, 0.71
20138000100012, D,  RENT,   98.58
20138000200060, H,  2013800020, 02.04.2018, WK, 006,    0,  25.05.2009, NULL,   C
20138000200060, H,  2013800020, 03.04.2017, WK, 006,    0,  25.05.2009, NULL,   C
20138000200060, H,  2013800020, 04.04.2016, WK, 006,    0,  25.05.2009, NULL,   C
20138000200060, D,  INSURE, 0.80
20138000200060, D,  RENT,   98.58
20138000500060, D,  LAUNDR, 1.29
```

All header columns are identical except the fourth column that is generated using this command:

```
format(dbo.[IH-PLACE-CHG].[START-DATE], 'dd.MM.yyyy') AS [2]
```

## Solution

If you need only the first value then you can use `First_Value()` window function:

```
FIRST_VALUE(format(dbo.[IH-PLACE-CHG].[START-DATE], 'dd.MM.yyyy')) OVER(PARTITION BY  cast(dbo.[RE-TENANCY].[TENANCY-REF] as nvarchar)) as [2]
```

And you can add a distinct operator on the headers query, the whole SQL command will be like:

```
select * 
from 
    (select Distinct 
         cast(dbo.[RE-TENANCY].[TENANCY-REF] as nvarchar) AS [0],
         'H' as [RowLevel],
         substring(convert(varchar(10),dbo.[RE-TENANCY].[TENANCY-REF]), 1, 10) AS [1],
         -- convert(varchar,dbo.[IH-PLACE-CHG].[START-DATE],104) AS [  ]
         FIRST_VALUE(format(dbo.[IH-PLACE-CHG].[START-DATE], 'dd.MM.yyyy')) OVER(PARTITION BY  cast(dbo.[RE-TENANCY].[TENANCY-REF] as nvarchar)) as [2],
         dbo.[RE-TENANCY].[RENT-GROUP] AS [3], 
         cast(substring( dbo.[RE-TENANCY].[TENANCY-REF],11,3) as nvarchar) AS [4]
, cast(substring( dbo.[RE-TENANCY].[TENANCY-REF],14,1) as nvarchar) AS [5]
, cast(format(dbo.[RE-TENANCY].[TNCY-START], 'dd.MM.yyyy') as nvarchar) AS [6]
, cast(format(dbo.[RE-TENANCY].[TNCY-END], 'dd.MM.yyyy') as nvarchar) AS [7]
, substring(dbo.[RE-TENANCY].[TNCY-STATUS],1,1) AS [8]
    FROM            
        dbo.[RE-EX-RAISE-DEBIT-DTL] 
    INNER JOIN
        dbo.[RE-TENANCY] ON dbo.[RE-EX-RAISE-DEBIT-DTL].REFERENCE = dbo.[RE-TENANCY].[TENANCY-REF] 
    INNER JOIN
        dbo.[IH-PLACE-CHG] ON substring(dbo.[RE-TENANCY].[TENANCY-REF],1,10) = dbo.[IH-PLACE-CHG].[PLACE-REF]

    union

select cast(dbo.[RE-TENANCY].[TENANCY-REF] as nvarchar) AS [0]
,'D' as [RowLevel]

, dbo.[RE-EX-RAISE-DEBIT-DTL].[ACCOUNT-CODE] AS [1]
, convert(varchar,[dbo].[RE-EX-RAISE-DEBIT-DTL].[CHARGE-AMT]) AS [2]
, '' AS [3]
, '' AS [4]
, '' AS [5]
, '' AS [6]
, '' AS [7]
, '' AS [8]
FROM            dbo.[RE-EX-RAISE-DEBIT-DTL] INNER JOIN
                         dbo.[RE-TENANCY] ON dbo.[RE-EX-RAISE-DEBIT-DTL].REFERENCE = dbo.[RE-TENANCY].[TENANCY-REF] INNER JOIN
                         dbo.[IH-PLACE-CHG] ON substring(dbo.[RE-TENANCY].[TENANCY-REF],1,10) = dbo.[IH-PLACE-CHG].[PLACE-REF]


) AS HBfile order by cast(HBfile.[0] as bigint), HBfile.[6] desc
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a WHERE clause to filter out the undesired header rows.   Desirability seems to be based on the first date column in your results.